# Apache Avro: Extending (Appending) Reader Schema without knowing Writer Schema

Tags: avro

I am aware of the Avro Reader‘s and Witer‘s schema projection mechanism.
I have a server which wants to add backwards-compatible new data elements to the reader‘s schema. The server does not want to know the exact writer’s schema as there are numerous clients out there.
Is it possible to do a limited schema evolution where e.g. optional things are only appended in a new reader schema?

I know that other techniques like JSON or also Protobuf might support that better, but I want to use Apache Open Source.